# clearing Jquery css changes on resize refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, less, media

As you can see from my example [here](http://jasonglover.co.uk). I am trying to make it so that when the window is re sized lower than 1000px; the CSS is cleared as so my .css file can take over.

it works if the window size starts lower than 1000px but not the other way around

```
$(window).resize(function(){

   if ($(window).width() >= 1000) {  

        var length = $('#left').height() - $('#sidebar').height() + $('#left').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {

    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var height = $('#sidebar').height() + 'px';

    if (scroll < $('#left').offset().top) {

        $('#sidebar').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '0'
        });

    } else if (scroll > length) {

        $('#sidebar').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'bottom': '0',
            'top': 'auto'
        });

    } else {

        $('#sidebar').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '0',
            'height': height
        });
    }
});

   }   
    else if ($(window).width() <= 1000) {
    $('#sidebar').css({
    'position': '',
    'bottom': '',
    'top': ''
     });
     $('#left').css({
    'position': '',
    'bottom': '',
    'top': ''
     });
    }

});
```

Comment: Just curious: Is there any reason not to do all of this with CSS3 media queries instead of jQuery?

Comment: Rather than setting your css properties to empty string, are you able to simply remove the style attribute? eg: `$('#left,#sidebar').removeAttr('style');`

Comment: Believe me if you could I would have done it already the main problem being that if you set something to postion:relative; it ignores the things above it if that makes sense

Comment: toggling classes is usually simpler approach

Comment: yes     $('#left,#sidebar').removeAttr('style'); works. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem the code isn't working the way it is, is because the scroll-function is within the window-resize function; I think you just need to shuffle the stuff around a bit:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).width() >= 1000) {

        var length = $('#left').height() - $('#sidebar').height() + $('#left').offset().top;

        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        var height = $('#sidebar').height() + 'px';

        if (scroll < $('#left').offset().top) {

            $('#sidebar').css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': '0'
            });

        } else if (scroll > length) {

            $('#sidebar').css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'bottom': '0',
                'top': 'auto'
            });

        } else {

            $('#sidebar').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '0',
                'height': height
            });
        }
    }
});

$(window).resize(function(){

    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
        $('#sidebar').css({
            'position': '',
            'bottom': '',
            'top': ''
         });
         $('#left').css({
            'position': '',
            'bottom': '',
            'top': ''
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: this worked nicely thank you. although it is giving me another weird issue .. at < 1009px it isn't fixing

Comment: At <1009? How odd... For me it works down to 1000px, and at 999 it switches. Do you have the changes live somewhere so I could look at it?

Comment: yes let me upload it, I didn't think you would reply. thanks again.
http://jasonglover.co.uk

weird thing is if i change it to >=970 it works




I have the standard @media's of bootstrap the only changing it at 992px

Comment: No problem! Don't like leaving stuff incomplete... ;-) Could you change it back to 1000 so I can see the bug? When I download the code and change it locally, it works just fine. Also, what kind of browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome, changed it to 1000

Comment: When you say that it isn't "fixing" at under 1009px width, do you mean the navigation on the right side doesn't scroll with you when you scroll down? That works for me (also using Chrome), so maybe I misunderstood the problem...? (Here's a printscreen, in Chrome, using the developer tools to show that the width is 1000px wide and the navigation has fixed itself to the top right: http://oi57.tinypic.com/aferea.jpg)

Comment: the right hand side bar isn't following my scrolling on anything less than 1016px; on both firefox and chrome. i can see on chrome that it doesn't apply the style onto the element before then

Comment: wait.. so I think i know why now. when you inspect an element on chrome and then re size the screen it tells you how many pixels you are at. However i tried it like in your screenshot by inspecting the body and it does say its at 999px/1000px and changes at that width however it also says that the @media part changes at something like 974 instead of 992px;

Comment: so i figure its including the scroll bar